# Can I get the derivation for the geodesic equation in Euclidean 3D?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Where can I find the derivation of the following formula for a [geodesic in 3D Euclidean](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086014000299) space expressed as:

> Calling $\vec u$ the tangent unit vector $\mathrm dr/\mathrm d s$ along the geodesic, and $\vec n$ the unit vector normal to the surface, the resulting equation of a geodesic reads

$$\frac{\mathrm d \vec u}{\mathrm d s} = -\left ( \vec u \cdot \frac{\mathrm d \vec n}{\mathrm ds}  \right ) \vec n=\vec u\times \left(\frac{\mathrm d\vec n}{\mathrm ds} \times \vec n\right)$$

?

I see a dot product between the tangent of the geodesic curve $\vec u$, and the tangent to the surface $\vec u \cdot \frac{\mathrm d \vec n}{\mathrm ds},$ that is to say, the projection of the vector representing the change in the normal vector to the surface (tangent to the surface) onto the unit tangent to the curve times the unit normal must be equal and opposite to the change in the tangent to the curve $\frac{\mathrm d \vec u}{\mathrm d s}$ in the middle expression. In the RHS there are two cross products.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing too interesting going on here. For ease of typing, I will use $'$ for $d/ds$ and let $\vec v = \vec n\times\vec u$.

The first equation just follows from $0 = (\vec u\cdot\vec n)' = \vec u'\cdot\vec n + \vec u\cdot\vec n{}'$.

The second equation is just vector algebra: Write $\vec n{}' = \lambda\vec u + \mu\vec v$, where, of course, $\lambda = \vec n{}'\cdot\vec u$. Then
\begin{align*}
\vec u\times(\vec n'\times\vec n) &= \vec u\times\big((\lambda\vec u + \mu\vec v)\times\vec n\big) \\
&= -\lambda\vec u\times\vec v + \mu\vec u\times\vec u = -\lambda\vec n,
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: How does $\vec n$ get to the RHS in the first equation if $0= \vec n \cdot \left( \frac{\mathrm d \vec u}{\mathrm d s}\right)  + \vec u \cdot \left (\frac{\mathrm d \vec n}{\mathrm ds}  \right )\implies   \vec n \cdot \frac{\mathrm d \vec u}{\mathrm d s}  =-\vec u \cdot \frac{\mathrm d \vec n}{\mathrm ds}  $?

Comment: @AntoniParellada Because, as you yourself said earlier on a different post, we know that for a geodesic $\vec u{}’$ must be a multiple of $\vec n$.

Comment: Namaste, Professor Shifrin!

Comment: Note to self: $$\begin{align} \vec u \times ((\lambda \vec u + \mu \vec v) \times \vec n) &= \vec u \times (- \vec n \times (\lambda \vec u + \mu \vec v))\\ &= \vec u (-\lambda \vec v + \mu \vec u)\\ &= -\lambda \vec n \end{align}.$$

Comment: $\vec n'$ is in the span of $\{\vec u, \vec v\}$ and hence, $\vec n{}' = \lambda\vec u + \mu\vec v.$ On a geodesic, $\vec n'$ is in the span of $\vec u,$ so $\lambda = \vec n{}'\cdot\vec u, $ the projection of $\vec n'$ on unit vector $\vec u.$ But then $\mu \vec v$ would be zero, wouldn't it? And if $\mu \vec v \neq 0,$ then $\lambda$ wouldn't be the projection of $\vec n'$ on $\vec u, $ would it?

Comment: It's still projection. I was showing you how to derive the second equality just by vector algebra. It holds quite generally. The geodesic condition comes solely from the first equality.